# Align contents in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I need to align the contents in a navigation bar so that they can always stay in the same place even if the language is changing and there are more/less letters but I can't seem to do that and when the language changes the whole bar breaks.

How it looks like in English and how it's supposed to allign: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWr2M.png
How it looks like in a Netherlands language when there are more letters: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX2LY.png

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Code:

```
div#sitenav {
    background: #303030;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    max-height: 52px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

div#sitenav ul,
div#sitenav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

div#sitenav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

div#sitenav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 17px 25px;
}

div#sitenav ul li a:hover, ul#main_nav_left li a:hover {
    background: #2db2ea !important;
    color: #fff; !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; !important;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; !important;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; !important;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(4) a {
    background: url(../css/images/navigation-divider.png) no-repeat right 50%;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1),  div#sitenav ul:nth-child(3) li {
    padding-left: 5.486em;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(3) li a {
    background-color: #4ea09c;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show some code ? It looks that you need to set a width on the elements which content changes

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I completely forgot.

Comment: If you just want them displayed inline, you can get rid of the `float` you applied.

Answer (score 0):

As you have 8 elements, you can give them a 12.5% width, and as display is set to inline just above, if you want to change the width you will have to set the display to block :

```
div#sitenav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 12.5%;
}
```

I cannot test this as I'm missing the rest of your code...